# Method to require another class, is not getting class

Tags: php, class, oop, phpexcel

I have lots of methods in a class to create reports using PHPExcel, I have one method to return a new instance of the PHPExcel object like so:

```
public function run_excel(){

    if(!class_exists(EXTPATH.'PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php')){
        require_once EXTPATH.'PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php';
    }

    return new PHPExcel();
}
```

I also want to add other PHPExcel functions into the run_excel to make titles and other stuff more dynamic to reduce my code, however I have tried assigning the PHPExcel method to a variable and returning that variable, but this doesn't work...

Example of what I want:

```
public function setup_phpexcel($title){

    if(!class_exists(EXTPATH.'PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php')){
        require_once EXTPATH.'PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php';
    }

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($title);

    return new PHPExcel();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: As you don't have a PHPExcel object at the point you're trying to use `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($title);`, you need to instantiate a new PHPExcel object and assign it to a variable, then you can set the title before returning that object

Comment: ouch... `require_once`, while `class_exists` will trigger an autoloader... You might want to look into [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php). IF you use [composer](http://getcomposer.org), `PHPExcel` is autoloaded anyway ([check packagist for details, too](https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpexcel))

Comment: I have a custom autoloader

Comment: @Richard: If you have an autoloader, why do you need the `class_exists` + `require_once` bits? And what's wrong with the composer-generated autoloader?

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the exact object that you're creating.

```
public function setup_phpexcel($title){

    if(!class_exists(EXTPATH.'PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php')){
        require_once EXTPATH.'PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php';
    }

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($title);

    return $objPHPExcel;
}
```

Currently you're modifying non-existing variable and then returning new, clean PHPExcel object.

Comment: Ahhh I did try that but then when I was calling $this->setup_phpexcel in the reports methods I wasnt assigning it to the var $objPHPExcel so it was returning undefined var! Thanks!